# Markdown And Escaping Javascript Line Breaks

Tags: javascript, erlang, markdown

I am writing a markdown compiler in Erlang for server-side use. Because it will need to work with clients I have decided to adopt the client side library (showdown.js) as the specification and then test my code for compatibility with that.

In the first couple of iterations I built up 260-odd unit tests which checked that my programme produced output which was compatible with what ***I thought was valid markdown*** based on reading the [syntax notes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

But now I am trying to write a javascript programme to generate my unit tests.

I have an input like:

```
"3 > 4\na"
```

I want to run 'showdown' on it to get:

```
"<p>3 &gt; 4\na</p>"
```

and I want to stitch this up into an EUnit assertion:

```
"?_assert(conv(\"3 > 4\na\") == \"<p>3 &gt; 4\na</p>\"),",
```

which is the valid Erlang syntax for the unit test. To make life easy, and to make the unit test generator portable I am doing it inside a web page so that by appending some lines to a javascript file and then view the page you get the new set of unit tests inside a `<textarea />` which you then copy down into the module to run EUnit.

The problem is that I can't get the line breaks to convert to `\n` in the string so I end up with:

```
"?_assert(conv(\"3 > 4
a\") == \"<p>3 &gt; 4
a</p>\"),",
```

I've tried converting the linefeeds to their escaped versions using code like:

```
text.replace("\\", "\\\\");
text.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

but no joy...

Comment: Could you use the character entity for backslash: &#92;

Comment: Can you modify this script to your needs? http://attacklab.net/showdown/

Comment: Zed - we use showdown as the script that generates the Unit Tests - the problem was just to escape the output from showdown..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom McNulty helped me out and pointed out that my regex's were super-pants, in particular I wasn't using the global flag :(

The working code is:

```
var converter;
var text = "";
var item;
var input;
var output;
var head;
var tail;
converter = new Attacklab.showdown.converter();
item = document.getElementById("tests");
for (var test in tests) {
  input = tests[test].replace(/[\n\r]+/gi,"\\n" );
  input = input.replace(/[\"]+/gi, "\\\"");
  output = converter.makeHtml(tests[test]).replace(/[\n\r]+/gi, "\\n");
  output = output.replace(/[\"]+/gi, "\\\"");
  text += "     ?_assert(conv(\"" + input + "\") == \"" + output + "\"),\n";
};
head = "unit_test_() -> \n    [\n";
tail = "\n    ].";
text = text.slice(0, text.length - 2);
item.value = head + text + tail;
```